# Python: Writing a csv output file of a tuple-valued dictionary

Tags: python, csv

How do I print the following dictionary into a csv file:

```
maxDict = {'test1': ('alpha', 2), 'test2': ('gamma', 2)}
```

So, that the output CSV looks as follows:

```
test1, test2
alpha, gamma
2, 2
```

p.s. I have asked this question before but not sure how to rearrange it in another way, i.e. tranposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be aware that the order of keys in a dict is implementation-defined, i.e. random. Therefore, it's advisable to [sort](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) them. Other than that, simply using the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module should work:

```
import csv
maxDict = {'test1': ('alpha', 2), 'test2': ('gamma', 2)} 
keys = sorted(maxDict.keys())
csvw = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'))
csvw.writerow(keys)
data = [maxDict[k] for k in keys]
for row in zip(*data):
  csvw.writerow(row)
```